# "Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy" even though I have allowed all origin/headers/methods

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Vue front end web application with .NET Core 3.1 Web API backend. I'm trying to do a POST to my API and I'm getting an error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myserver/myapi/address/4567' (redirected from 'http://myserver/myapi/address/4567') from origin 'http://myserver' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

My web API sits at: `https://myserver/myapi`

My Vue web application sits at: `https://myserver/mysite`

In my .NET's Startup.cs:

```
private readonly string mySitePolicy = "mysite";

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: mySitePolicy,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
    });

    services.AddSingleton<AddressRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<CustomerRepository>();

    services.AddControllers();

    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(o =>
    {
        o.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors(policyName: mySitePolicy);

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

I have allowed all origins/headers/methods. All my GET request succeeded, only the POST call fails. What's causing the error? How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the whole configure section pls?

Comment: Hi @Farid, be sure the call to `UseCors` must be placed after `UseRouting`, but before `UseAuthorization`.

Comment: @Sergey , I've added the whole Configure and ConfigureServices codes.

Comment: @Rena I did put UseCors after UseRouting. Sorry I just got back from vacation.

Answer (score 0):

This CORS error is very frequently a false positive. IN other words, the problem is totally unrelated to CORS - but the server returns that error, anyway.
You need to look at the server log (enable it, if you don't have it) and see the actual exception

Answer (score -2):

> ... from origin 'http://myserver' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

> My Vue web application sits at: https://myserver/mysite

You think that the javascript origin is `https://myserver/mysite` but browser suggests the js origin to be `http://myserver`. There are two ways,

## 1. Change to Same Origin

Change your javascript origin from `http://myserver` to `https://myserver`, so the front-end javascript is of the same origin.

## 2. Allow CORS in the Back-End

```c
            options.AddPolicy(name: mySitePolicy,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.WithOrigins("http://myserver",
                                                      "https://myserver");
                              });
```

You can update the question by posting the headers, especially `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, to see if your CORS configuration works.

Comment: I did allow all origin though. In my AddPolicy(), I put AllowAnyOrigin() so the calling site should not matter. (at least that's what I think)